# ValueError: matplotlib display text must have all code points < 128 or use Unicode strings

Tags: arrays, python-2.7

In my code I get an array like this:

```
array(['2.83100e+07', '2.74000e+07', '2.79400e+07'],dtype='|S11')
```

How can I "cut" my values like:

```
2.83100e+07 --> 2.831 ?
```

Best regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using a `for` loop and `round(n)`

```
In [23]: round(66.66666666666,4)
Out[23]: 66.6667

In [24]: round(1.29578293,6)
Out[24]: 1.295783
```

> help on round():

round(number[, ndigits]) -> floating point number

Round a number to a given precision in decimal digits (default 0 digits). This always returns a floating point number. Precision may be negative

Comment: Thanks that was the right idea! Now it works perfect! :)